# Replacing xml node from another xml

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

i use Java and I have 2 xml files like

```
<xml>
<a value="5">
<b value="7">
<c>
<d value="9">
</c>
<xml>
```

and

```
<xml>
<c>
<d value="8">
</c>
<xml>
```

So what i want is for every node in second xml if there exists with same node path in first xml, replace the first xml's node with the second xml's node.For these xmls, i expect

```
 <xml>
 <a value="5">
 <b value="7">
 <c>
 <d value="8">
 </c>
 <xml>
```

Many Thanks for Your Help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Sax parser and iterate through second XML and get all the available nodes. Or use DOM for that. Same way get all nodes in first XML. Then write a logic to find the matching nodes. Then use DOM to edit first XML. Try it your self so that you can learn. See how to edit XML [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

Answer (score 0):

there man ways to read xml and write xml like DOM parser , jaxB so i would prefer to use JAXB marshall and unmarshaller so that you can have an object of your xml file and to set the value and get the value becomes easier